# Работа с датами в Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Дана задача выделения индикатора присутствия скидки и номер дня, когда есть плановая скидка на конкретные продукты. Данные по скидкам хранятся в таблице вида:

```py
+-------------+------------+------------+
| ProductName | PromoStart |  PromoEnd  |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| A           | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-13 |
| C           | 2019-02-25 | 2019-03-03 |
| B           | 2019-02-04 | 2019-02-10 |
| D           | 2019-03-04 | 2019-03-10 |
| A           | 2019-03-18 | 2019-03-24 |
| B           | 2019-04-08 | 2019-04-14 |
| C           | 2019-04-15 | 2019-04-21 |
| D           | 2019-04-22 | 2019-04-28 |
| B           | 2019-05-20 | 2019-05-26 |
| A           | 2019-06-24 | 2019-06-30 |
| ...         | ...        | ...        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Я решил эту задачу следующей функцией:

```py
df_date = pd.DataFrame()
for product_title in df['ProductName'].unique():
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='D'),
        'ProductName': product_title,
        'IsPromo': 0,
        'DayInPromo': 0
    })

    for it in df[(df['ProductName'] == product_title)].index:
        A = pd.date_range(start=df.loc[it, 'PromoStart'], end=df.loc[it, 'PromoEnd'], freq='D')
        df_temp.loc[df_temp['Date'].isin(A), 'IsPromo'] = 1

    count=0
    for it in df_temp.index:
        if (df_temp.loc[it, 'IsPromo'] == 1):
            count += 1
            df_temp.loc[it, 'DayInPromo'] = count
        else:
            count = 0

    df_date = pd.concat([df_date, df_temp], axis=0, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

В результате я получаю необходимую мне таблицу, где количество строк = кол-во продуктов * кол-во дней:

```
+------------+-------------+---------+------------+
|    Date    | ProductName | IsPromo | DayInPromo |
+------------+-------------+---------+------------+
| 2019-01-07 | A           | 1       | 1          |
| 2019-01-08 | A           | 1       | 2          |
| 2019-01-09 | A           | 1       | 3          |
| 2019-01-10 | A           | 1       | 4          |
| ...        | ...         | ...     | ...        |
| 2019-12-14 | D           | 0       | 0          |
| 2019-12-15 | D           | 0       | 0          |
| 2019-12-16 | D           | 1       | 1          |
| 2019-12-17 | D           | 1       | 2          |
| ...        | ...         | ...     | ...        |
+------------+-------------+---------+------------+
```

Но, как мне кажется, я решаю задачу не совсем в стиле `Python` и `pandas`, используя циклы. Есть ли возможность переписать данную задачу в другом стиле?

Comment: у вас таблица в БД лежит? мб обычным запросом будет логичней? Работа с данными осуществляется обычно там где они хранятся.

Comment: @EugeneDennis, нет, excel-файлик. А если бы в БД, то как это можно сделать с помощью запросов?

Comment: @Ratatuy129, должны ли присутствовать даты __не попадающие__ в диапазоны в результирующей таблице?

Comment: @MaxU, если я правильно понял - нет, не должны. Именно поэтому в коде далее для слияния этой таблицы с моей огромной исходной я делаю `df = df.merge(promo_dates, on='Date', how=left)`.
P.S. неправильно я понял. В данной таблице `promo_dates` должны присутствовать даты не из диапазонов скидки. Для этих дат у меня значение = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не нужно в таблице учитывать даты, когда на товар НЕ было акции, то, вероятно, можно сделать так:

```
res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(row['PromoStart'], row['PromoEnd'], freq='D'),
      'ProductName': row['ProductName'], 'DayInPromo':i})
      for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['ProductName', 'Date'])

res['DayInPromo']=res.groupby('DayInPromo').cumcount().add(1)
```

Получим:

```
    Date    ProductName DayInPromo
0   2019-01-07  A   1
1   2019-01-08  A   2
2   2019-01-09  A   3
3   2019-01-10  A   4
4   2019-01-11  A   5
5   2019-01-12  A   6
6   2019-01-13  A   7
28  2019-03-18  A   1
29  2019-03-19  A   2
30  2019-03-20  A   3
31  2019-03-21  A   4
32  2019-03-22  A   5
33  2019-03-23  A   6
34  2019-03-24  A   7
63  2019-06-24  A   1
64  2019-06-25  A   2
65  2019-06-26  A   3
66  2019-06-27  A   4
67  2019-06-28  A   5
68  2019-06-29  A   6
69  2019-06-30  A   7
14  2019-02-04  B   1
15  2019-02-05  B   2
16  2019-02-06  B   3
...
```

Comment: А если нужно, просто сделать `reindex` на основе `date_range`. Благодарю за ответ!